# Filenames cause wrong order when using mencoder to create a video from a sequence of pictures

Tags: command-line, mencoder

I would like to create a video of pictures with `mencoder`, I can do it with:

```
mencoder mf://*.jpeg -mf fps=50 -ovc copy -oac copy output.avi
```

But the problem comes from the name of my pictures...indeed, I have `video000001.jpg`, ..., `video0000100,` ... so when it creates the video, the sequence isn't respected... it classifies `video10000.jpeg`, `video100000.jpeg`

With python, we can use this command:

```
sorted(glob.glob('*.jpeg'), key=os.path.getmtime)
```

How can I have an equivalent to achieve my video in console with `mencoder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via

```
mencoder mf://video{000001..100000}.jpeg -mf fps=50 -ovc copy -oac copy output.avi
```

But there could be an error, if the list is too long, eg `video{00000000..10000000}.jpg`

```
argument list too long: touch
```

Therefore it's better to create a sorted list

```
find . -type f -name 'video*.jpeg' | sort -V > list
```

and use the list

```
mencoder mf://@list -mf fps=50 -ovc copy -oac copy output.avi
```

Comment: Thanks for help but it doesnt work... :(

Comment: And what doesn't work?

Comment: For the first one, i get : "Liste d'arguments trop longue" and for the second, i get "Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type"...

Comment: Yes, you're rigth. The 2nd option is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mencoder` with the `mf://@list.txt` switch where you can generate a list of files in `list.txt` as you want, for instance with your python command above.

See also: [mencoder and sequence of pictures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656371/mencoder-and-sequence-of-pictures)

Answer (score 0):

i dont have 50 rep to comment. 
The answer provided by A.B. works. although the command should read

`mencoder mf://@list -mf fps=50 -ovc copy -oac copy -o output.avi`

The syntax above results in the following.

`mencoder mf://@list -mf fps=50 -ovc copy -oac copy output.avi
MEncoder 1.2.1 (Debian), built with gcc-5.3.1 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
Exiting... (No output file specified, please see the -o option.)`